# Convert two channels into a single channel left or right with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, python-3.6

I have some .wav files and I would like to convert their frequency (fs) and number of channels (nchannels). I am using ffmpeg on a Jupyter Notebook, Python 3.6. I used the following command and it works.

```
cmd= 'ffmpeg -i %s -ar %d -ac %d %s.wav'%(filepath,fs,nchannel,wavfilename)
os.system(cmd)
```

However, when converting two channels into a single channel, I just want ffmpeg takes only left (or right) channel instead of an average of two signal. If I use map channel as follows, would that be correct? This creates wav files but I am not sure if only one channel is taken.

```
'ffmpeg -i %s -ar %d -map_channel 0.0.0 %s.wav(filepath,fs,wavfilename)'
```

If not, how can I modify my code above to achieve that? I also tried;

```
'ffmpeg -i %s -af channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL -ar %d %s.wav'%(filepath,fs,wavfilename)'
```

but this created empty wav files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [channelsplit filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit):

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL" front_left.wav
```

See a list of channel names with `ffmpeg -layouts`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to do all the conversions (to .wav, fs, channel) at once that s why i asked how can i modify my code, I am just having trouble to incorporate your solution into my command line. But maybe it is not possible?

Comment: @kutlus I don't know python, and I assumed it was more of a ffmpeg question than a python question. Try `cmd= 'ffmpeg -i %s -af channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL -ar %d %s.wav'%(filepath,fs,nchannel,wavfilename)`. You won't need `-ac` because the output will be mono, as you requested.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi Ilogan, this command creates wav file but they are empty, i tried the command both without quotes and with  the quates as in  cmd= 'ffmpeg -i %s -af "channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL" -ar %d %s.wav'%(filepath,fs,wavfilename). Created files are empty, any ideas?

Comment: @kutlus Is the problem with the python code or with ffmpeg? Try the ffmpeg command unscripted, manually in a command line interface. Does it work? If not show your actual command and the complete log from the command.

Comment: I tried on the terminal unscripted; [Parsed_channelsplit_0 @ 0x2053f80] Option 'channels' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2053280] Error initializing filter 'channelsplit' with args 'channel_layout=stereo:channels=FL'
Error opening filters! thanks. I have updated my question, does the command line with map channel look correct? Thanks

Comment: @kutlus Need the **complete** log and actual command. You can put it on a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: thanks Ilogan, the command line on the terminal created the wav file but empty again.  I will just use the command with map_channel, it should be correct https://superuser.com/questions/702552/ffmpeg-audio-stereo-to-mono-using-only-left-channel.  I appreciate your time.